# Best way to pull a date range using baseballR?

Tags: r, date, wildcard

I am attempting to pull game information from the MLB api. I am able to pull it date by date, but I cannot use the ** wild card for the day or I get a HTTP error 400.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(baseballr)

games <- get_game_pks_mlb(date = '2021-04-01', level_ids = 1)

games %>%
  select(game_pk, teams.away.team.name, teams.home.team.name)

   game_pk teams.away.team.name  teams.home.team.name
1   634642    Toronto Blue Jays      New York Yankees
2   634645    Cleveland Indians        Detroit Tigers
3   634638      Minnesota Twins     Milwaukee Brewers
```

However, I don't want to have to run a scan for each day, because 1) that will take ages, and 2) that's sending a lot of requests. Plus after I pull all of this information I will have to segment again and pull pitch by pitch information.

I think some kind of for loop would be able to make this work, but for some reason I am just really bad at understanding for and while loops.

EDIT: I tried the following solutions based on original expectations and got these outcomes:

```
x <- c("2021-04-01", "2021-04-02")
games <- as_tibble()

for (x in x) {
  games <- rbind(games, get_game_pks_mlb(date = x, level_ids = 1))
}

Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

```
games <- get_game_pks_mlb(date = x, level_ids = 1)

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       http://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/
                     (right here) ------^
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```r
dates <- c("2021-04-01", "2021-04-02", "2021-04-03")

games <- data.frame()

for (date in dates) {
  games <- rbind(games, get_game_pks_mlb(date = date, level_ids = 1))
}
```

So first create a vector of your dates, you want to retrieve, than loop over those dates and bind those data.frames together. It's not the best way, but a good way to start.

Comment: Or use `map` `map_dfr(dates, ~ get_game_pks_mlb(date = .x, level_ids = 1)) %>%  select(game_pk, teams.away.team.name, teams.home.team.name)`

Comment: My first thought was to create the vector of dates manually., but I'd like to find a way to automate date creation rather than typing every day. I plan on doing this over many years, so that would be 200ish dates per year (I think there's just under 200 days in the regular season).

Comment: You could try something like `seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by="days")`.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using a combo of map_dfr and seq to pull the information. It only took me 25 minutes to pull all that data... now i have to pull each game after I got the ID...